# UnsatisfiedLinkError when deploying an iOS libGDX game with RoboVM and IDEA

Tags: ios, intellij-idea, libgdx, robovm

I'm trying to deploy the base libGDX game (the default project that is created with libGDX's setup tool, version 1.5.5) to an iPhone 5 using IDEA 14.1.1 and latest RoboVM snapshot but I'm getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError. Using the simulator I get the same error:

```
2015-04-09 11:06:06.847 IOSLauncher[2107:552074] [debug] IOSApplication: iOS version: 8.2
2015-04-09 11:06:06.848 IOSLauncher[2107:552074] [debug] IOSApplication: Running in 32-bit mode
2015-04-09 11:06:06.851 IOSLauncher[2107:552074] [debug] IOSApplication: scale: 2.0
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com/badlogic/gdx/backends/iosrobovm/IOSGLES20.init()V
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGLES20.init(Native Method)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGLES20.<init>(IOSGLES20.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSApplication.didFinishLaunching(IOSApplication.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSApplication$Delegate.didFinishLaunching(IOSApplication.java)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplicationDelegate$ObjCProxy.$cb$application$didFinishLaunchingWithOptions$(Unknown Source)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)
    at com.mangoprotocol.test.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java)
```

Both in the simulator and the actual iPhone device the default libGDX white image is shown for less than a second and then the game exits, spitting the previous stack trace to the IDEA console.

I think I've followed correctly all configuration steps in order to get this running, but I'm obviously missing something.

Any idea about how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was missing a space (yeah...) between the name and the key in the *iosSignIdentity* parameter in the build.gradle file.